# Class Vs Abstract Class Vs Interfaces

Tags: class, interface, abstract

What is the difference between a Plain Class Vs Abstract Class Vs Interfaces. Kindly, explain the same using snippets and demo.

Answer (score 0):

Class:

It is a class without any abstract members. You can instantiate normal Class where as you cant instantiate Interface and Abstract class; you can just inherit from Abstract and Interface. Inherit from it (unless the class is sealed), use its methods, override those methods, etc.

Abstract Class:

May/mayn't contain Implementations; At least one member will not be implemented. A Class may inherit from a single Base class; multiple inheritance not allowed. Members have access modifiers May contain fields, properties, constructors, destructors, methods, events and indexers.

Interface:

Does not contain Implementations Interface can inherit from a number of interfaces(Multiple inheritance supported) Members are automatically public May contain properties, methods, events and indexers
[image: Implemented very basic difference of instantiation of a class and multiple inheritence]